# HTTP through Sockets in C: Basic file server fails to properly return file

Tags: c, string, file, http, sockets

I'm trying to write a basic HTTP file server using sockets in C and have two main problems.

First, when I try to access "ip:port/" through a browser, I get the index.html file but it's in complete gibberish.  However, when I access "ip:port/not_in_directory" my little custom 404 message comes back just fine.  If I set the default file to a existing pdf file, gibberish comes back as well (length of pdf gibberish).

Secondly, when I try to access "ip:port/file_that_exists", I get my 404 instead of the correct file.  While debugging, I do see that scratch_pad has the correct file name, with no excess or missing characters, but !access(scratch_pad, R_OK) still comes out to be 0.  Is there some necessary cast even though access() takes a char* for the file name?

EDIT: Second issue has been solved (I was using a pointer to deallocated buffer as file name).  However, everything that's picked up by the browser is gibberish.  I'm removing more non-essential code.

```
#define FILE_NOT_FOUND "HTTP/1.0 404 FILE NOT FOUND\r\n"
#define FILE_FOUND "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
#define SERVER_NAME "Server: Test Server\r\n"
#define CONTENT_TYPE "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
#define DATE "Date: "
#define MESSAGE_BREAK "\r\n"
#define NOT_FOUND_HTML "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n<body>\n<p>Nope</p>\n</body>\n</html>\r\n"

  if(!access(pulled_name, R_OK | W_OK)) {
      printf("file found on server\n");
      server_file = fopen(pulled_name, "rb+");
      fseek(server_file, 0L, SEEK_END);
      file_size = ftell(server_file);
      fseek(server_file, 0l, SEEK_SET);
      printf("opened successfully and set file_size to %i\n", file_size);
      getting_time = time(NULL);
      c_time = localtime(&getting_time);
      current_time = asctime(c_time);
      printf("set time for message\n");

  message = malloc((int) strlen(FILE_FOUND)
                + (int) strlen(SERVER_NAME)
                + (int) strlen(CONTENT_TYPE)
                + (int) strlen(DATE)
                + (int) strlen(current_time)
                + (int) strlen(MESSAGE_BREAK));

  printf("malloc'ed message\n");

  message_size = (int)(strlen(message)*sizeof(char));     
  memset(message, 0, message_size);
  strcpy(message, FILE_FOUND);
  strcat(message, SERVER_NAME);
  strcat(message, CONTENT_TYPE);
  strcat(message, DATE);
  strcat(message, current_time);
  strcat(message, MESSAGE_BREAK);
  printf("built message\n");

  printf("set message_size to %i\n", message_size);
  while(total_sent < message_size) {
    n = send(new_socket_fd, message, message_size, 0);
    if (n==-1) {
      printf("error sending message\n");
      break;
    }
    total_sent += n;
    printf("sent %i\n", total_sent);
  }
  free(message);

  total_sent = 0;
  while(total_sent < file_size) {
    n = send(new_socket_fd, server_file, file_size, 0);
    if (n==-1) {
      printf("error sending file\n");
      break;
    }
    total_sent += n;
    printf("sent %i\n", total_sent);
  }
  fclose(server_file);
  close(new_socket_fd);
  printf("closed client connection!\n");
```

Comment: Please supply the entire file somewhere so we can play around with it.

Comment: That's a lot of code to read through. Perhaps step through with a debugger to see when something doesn't make sense. By the way, it'll be a lot more efficient, and probably easier to grok, to just send the headers with `writev()` and then relay the document with `sendfile()`. There's no need to build a temporary buffer for the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There several instances of this mistake:

```
memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
```

when the type of the first argument is a `char*`, which means the buffer will not be filled with null characters but only the first `sizeof(char*)` bytes (typically 4 or 8). In this case, it means that `buffer` may not be null terminated (as `recv()` does not append null characters). Both `printf()` and `strtok()` require string arguments to be null terminated. It is common to see garbage characters printed after a string with a call to `printf("%s", p);` with a non-null terminated string.

Fix all `memset()` calls by explicitly specifying the size of the buffer pointed to by the first argument:

```
const size_t BUFFER_SIZE      = 512;
const size_t SCRATCH_PAD_SIZE = 256;
buffer                        = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);     /*Check return value*/
scratch_pad                   = malloc(SCRATCH_PAD_SIZE);/*to ensure success.*/
memset(buffer,      0, BUFFER_SIZE);
memset(scratch_pad, 0, SCRATCH_PAD_SIZE);
```

The `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` so it can be omitted from the `malloc()` argument.

---

Other misuse of `memset()`:

```
memset(message, '0', sizeof(message));
```

- `'0'` is a the character zero, not null
- `sizeof(message)` is the `sizeof(char*)`

change to:

```
memset(message, 0, /* the actual size of message*/ );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out.  I've corrected the buffer memset'ing as you advised and now when printing the incoming HTTP message, all the garbage characters are no longer displayed.  I also just use scratch_pad as a string instead of buffer but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things in your code that don't look too good.

Here:

```
   buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*512);
   scratch_pad = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
```

scratch_pad is a pointer to an allocated area.

But then you lose your pointer to that area and set scratch_pad to point into buffer:

```
   printf("request:\n%s\n", buffer);
   scratch_pad = strtok(buffer, "/");
```

Then here:

```
   if (!strncmp(scratch_pad, "HTTP", 4)) {
       scratch_pad = "index.html";
       printf("request was for root directory\n");
   }
```

you point scratch_pad to a constant string.

When you did

```
free(scratch_pad);
```

I'd have expected for all Hell to get loose.

Your approach to tokenisation is a bit risky. The first consequence I see is that you would accept a `GETLOST` method as a synonym for `GET`, and you would have problems handling paths (e.g. `GET /js/main.js HTTP/1.0`):

```
scratch_pad = strtok(buffer, "/");
printf("pulling request type\n");

if (!strncmp(scratch_pad, "GET", 3)) {
  printf("this is a Get\n");
  scratch_pad = strtok(NULL, " ");
  printf("pulling file name: >%s<\n", scratch_pad);
  if (!strncmp(scratch_pad, "HTTP", 4)) {
    scratch_pad = "index.html";
    printf("request was for root directory\n");
  }
  printf("requested file: %s\n", scratch_pad);
}
```

As for `access()`, if scratch_pad has the correct file **and the server is running in the web root**, then `access()` ought to return 0. If it does not, verify the value of `errno`.

**UPDATE**

As I was writing above, `scratch_pad` is (or may be) a pointer *inside* `buffer`. So when you do:

```
free(buffer);
if(!access(scratch_pad, R_OK)) {
```

it *might* happen (shouldn't, not for some milliseconds at least, but hey...) that the area pointed by `buffer` is trashed. Then also whatever `scratch_pad` points to will be.

And at that point, `access` (which might well be the one doing the trashing, now that I think about it) will work on garbage, and refuse proceeding.

To check, just do:

if (access(scratch_pad, R_OK))
   {
      printf("Cannot access file '%s'\n", scratch_pad);
   }
   else
   {
      ...

To avoid this, tokenise differently `buffer`.

For example:

char *space;
   char *http;

// Buffer is GET /this/path/to/file/name HTTP/1.0...
   if (!strncmp(buffer, "GET ", 4))
      // Not a GET
   if (NULL == (space = strchr(buffer+4, ' ')))
      // ERROR: there is no second space.
   if (!strncmp(space + 1, 'HTTP/1.', 7))
      // ERROR: the GET doesn't end with HTTP/1.something
   // Now all buffer between buffer+4 and space is the file name
   len = space-buffer-4;
   strncpy(scratch_pad, buffer + 4, len);
   // Terminate string
   scratch_pad[len] = 0x0;

// Now scratch_pad contains the filename complete with /, but it is relative
   // to the wrong path; we want it to start from our document root.
   // So instead

#define DOCUMENT_ROOT "./"
   len = space-buffer-4;
   strcpy(scratch_pad, DOCUMENT_ROOT);
   strncpy(scratch_pad + strlen(DOCUMENT_ROOT), buffer + 4, len);
   len += strlen(DOCUMENT_ROOT);
   // Terminate string. Now it is: .//path/to/file
   scratch_pad[len] = 0x0;
   // We actually ought to run realpath() here...

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I now just use scratch_pad as a string and don't malloc anything for it.  I also changed the comparison to "GET ", 4, which will not allow a GETLOST hit.  Can you think of better delimiters to continue using tokenization or a more proper method of pulling a file name from an HTTP message?

Comment: Ther errno is 36, "file name too long", but my test is just "index.html", which works just fine when I set it manually in the code...

Comment: For tokenising you ought to search for the delimiting characters with `strchr` and copy the resulting string in a separate buffer, or use a "state machine" char by char. For the rest, I'm updating my answer; I may have spotted another issue.

Comment: Yeah, checking scratch_pad after freeing buffer caused the access failure.  Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `Date: ...` header is not newline terminated, therefore the MESSAGE_BREAK is swallowed. Also, I am unsure why you add +1 to all string lengths.

Answer (score 0):

two things that looked strange to me:

1. why are you always sending 404 message before coming to the real content of the file?
2. the second send() is wrong, why are you sending the file descriptor? where is your buffer? you should provide the buffer pointer and update it with each loop.

hint: gcc -Wall is your friend.